# Why are some keydown events ignored when attached to the document?

Tags: javascript, html

Some of my keydown events seem to be getting dropped when I tab out of, and then back into, an input field on the page.

If you run the following code, and tab into the input, you should see all console printouts, as expected.  But if you tab out of the field and "all the way back around" into the input (or, better yet, right back into it via `Shift + Tab`), there is no console printout for the keydown handler.  The same behavior occurs on the "other side" of the input; if you tab in, tab back out (again via `Shift + Tab`), and then tab back in, the console printout for the keydown handler is equally absent.  Why might this be?

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (!e.repeat && e.key == 'Tab') {
    console.log(`(${Math.round(performance.now())}ms) eyyyy, nice keydown`);
    console.log(` - You were focused on ${document.activeElement}`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(` - You should now be focused on ${document.activeElement}`);
      console.log(` - You're a very special lass/lad/whathaveyou`);
    });
  }
});

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('focus', () => {
  console.log(`(${Math.round(performance.now())}ms) input focused`);
});
```

```html
<input id="test">
```

I've tried attaching the keydown handler to `window` and `document` with the same results for both.  I've also tried adding `{ capture: true }` to the `addEventListener('keydown'...` call with no difference in behavior.

I'm using Chrome Version 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: I'm using the same last version of Chrome that you do and for me it works as expected on Shift+Tab returning everything is captured in the console printdown

Comment: That's wild :(  I don't know why we'd be getting different behaviors on the same version of the browser.  You're seeing the console printouts when Shift+Tab brings you back into the input field?  Shift+Tab gives me the printouts in all other instances, but when it brings the input back into focus the `keydown` printouts are missing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh now I got it, you claiming that you can't see the printouts out off the keydown event listener, that because of the iframe code window, and your key down event listener is registered to window object, so when you press tab you are out off iframe and that's why when you returned that listener isn't working. Just try it on the normal page or add other elements to iframe and you will see that when you navigating back and force the key down listener will always work

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (!e.repeat && e.key == 'Tab') {
    console.log(`(${Math.round(performance.now())}ms) eyyyy, nice keydown`);
    console.log(` - You were focused on ${document.activeElement}`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(` - You should now be focused on ${document.activeElement}`);
      console.log(` - You're a very special lass/lad/whathaveyou`);
    });
  }
});

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('focus', () => {
  console.log(`(${Math.round(performance.now())}ms) input focused`);
});
```

```html
<input id="test" />

<input />

<input />
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but the problem still exists without adding inputs and whether it's in the iframe or the code is pulled out into a separate document and loaded in its own window.  I can't add arbitrary input fields after the field in question as a fix.  The problem may very well have something to do with the input being the first and last element of the document/window that is "tabbable", but if that's the case, I need a fix that addresses what I'm doing wrong with the event listener attachments, not one that sidesteps the issue by adding extra inputs.